# TypeScript Built in XML Validator

Tags: javascript, xml, typescript

I need to use typescript to validate specific string valid XML or not. I did some search but could not find any build-in lib to call validation. Does anyone know if there's a way I can achieve XML validation in typescript or any sample code I could refer to?

Comment: What would you have used if you were using plain JavaScript? TypeScript is not supposed to provide that kind of functionality, but type definitions (typings) for an XML library may be available. Consider searching for a specific library and showing an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050759/validate-xml-syntax-structure-with-node-js