# how to validate if an XML is "well formed" in nodejs

Tags: node.js, xml, xml-validation, xmllint

I'm working with nodejs and I need to validate if an xml is well formed, just that.

I do not want to use xsd because the xml nodes can change.. and I do not know how to use it only to validate syntax.

XML valid

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from> 
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

XML invalid

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from> 
<heading>Remi
```

I just need to validate that the xml syntax is correct and get true if it is well formed or false if not.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate XML Syntax / Structure with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050759/validate-xml-syntax-structure-with-node-js)

Comment: I would try to [parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890655/the-best-node-module-for-xml-parsing) it and return false if it fails.