# How to check the string is xml or not using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

I need some help. I am checking the input string is `json/xml` using Node.js. I am explaining my code which gives the output to check the given string is json or not.

```
isJSON = (str) => { 
    try { 
        return (JSON.parse(str) && !!str); 
    } catch (e) { 
        return false; 
    }
} 

const result= isJSON(string);
```

So here I am able to check whether the string i.e `string` is JSON or not. In similar way I need to check for XML content.

Lets say I have the string which is given below:

```
const string = '<config xmlns="http://tail-f.com/ns/config/1.0">
   <devices xmlns="http://tail-f.com/ns/ncs">
      <global-settings>
         <read-timeout>120</read-timeout>

     </global-settings>
</devices>
</config>';
```

So I need to check the above content is XML content or not using node.js. Can anybody help me to resolve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050759/validate-xml-syntax-structure-with-node-js

Comment: @gaetanoM: That module is throwing this `
Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlChecker - Not found` error.

Comment: see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050759/validate-xml-syntax-structure-with-node-js)

Answer (score 2):

In XML the first character will always be "<". In JSON, apart from trivial cases, the first non-space character will be "[" or "{". So it's easy to decide between them.

After that, to decide whether it's well-formed XML or well-formed JSON, you need to put it through a parser.

(Incidentally, we haven't found an XML parser on node.js that has a really high level of conformance in terms of handling edge cases. But there are plenty that are good enough for practical purposes.)